# How to change root view controller to view controller in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new to Iphone programming.While I am creating project I have taken root view controller class.By default Appdelegate.h,.m,root viewcontroller.h,.m, were created,first class is root view controller and 2nd class is view controller which I have taken.When I am running the project in simulator first view is displaying table view.Now what I want to do is, when I run project I want to display 2nd class i.e, view controller not root view controller(I dont want to display table view first i want to display view).Is it possible to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. What you need to do is, Create an object of your 2nd class in AppDelegate.m file and assign it as a root view.

Example:

```
#import "ExampleClass.h"

ExampleClass *exp = [[ExampleClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExampleClass" bundle:nil]];
exp.title = @"ExampleClass";

// Navigation controller
self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:exp] autorelease]; 

[self.window setRootViewController:self.navigationController];
```